# angular js variable not work

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ngcordova

**index.html**

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="removeTask(10);">remove</button>
<div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.removeTask = function(taskId) {
        alert("Task Id is " + taskId);
    };
    var statement = "";
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
        statement = "select * from objects where o.TYPES=' + taskId' GROUP BY objectid";
```

The `alert` message work perfectly, but when I try to use the variable `taskId` on `select` statement it does not work.

Comment: Well first off mate why are you trying to do a database call via Angular? Secondly, you are trying to access 'o' which I assume is meant to be objects but you never cast 'o' to be 'objects' you need to say `from objects as o where...`

Comment: $id must come from via POST or GET
like  

$id = $_POST['taskId];
then


"select * from objects where o.TYPES=$id GROUP BY objectid";

Comment: is sqlite offline database and when i put for example o.TYPES='10' is work perffect

Comment: the true statement is  statement = "select * from objects as o  where o.TYPES='+taskId' GROUP BY objectid";

Comment: [Web SQL Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database) is **deprecated**. While it is still popular on mobile devices, look into using modern alternatives.

Comment: Look at -- [Why is Web SQL database deprecated?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the db transaction inside the function.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    var statement = "";
    $scope.removeTask = function(taskId) {
        alert("Task Id is " + taskId);

        db.transaction(function (tx) {
        //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
        statement = "select * from objects where o.TYPES='+taskId' GROUP BY objectid"; 
        };
    };
```

Function arguments such as `taskId` are available only inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.removeTask = function(taskId){
    alert("Task Id is "+taskId);
    $scope.taskId = taskId;
};


var statement = "";

 db.transaction(function (tx) {

    //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');

    statement = "select * from objects where o.TYPES='+$scope.taskId+' GROUP BY objectid";
```

Note that you must assign the task id to a scope variable to use it later.

Comment: The OP is using `ngCordova` [$cordovaSQLite](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware. Removed that paragraph.

Comment: BTW, I don't see the problem, look at the JSBin (http://jsbin.com/zareperowu/1/edit?html,js,output) - the alert works perfectly. Left out the web database stuff for clarity.